# What is the best way to write multiple aggregate views in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have the following snippet:

```
 sum_games       = GameHistory.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('games'))
 sum_played      = GameHistory.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('games_played'))
 sum_goals       = GameHistory.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('goals'))
 sum_assists     = GameHistory.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('assists'))
 sum_clean_sheet = GameHistory.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('clean_sheet'))
```

What is the best and cleanest way to write this? Because right now I am just repeating myself but with different variables.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can separate them with commas.

```
stats = GameHistory.objects.all().aggregate(sum_games=Sum('games'), sum_games_played=Sum('games_played'), ...)
```

and then access like so:

```
print(stats['sum_games'])
print(stats['sum_games_played'])
```

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#joins-and-aggregates